# Spring JPA: Find all records from the past or now

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have  entity `Ticket` which has a field `nextActionDate` as `Date`/`Timestamp`.

I am heavily unclear how to select all records which are due to an update, i.e. is either now or in the past (with additional parameters).

In my `JPARepository` I want to annotate the method like

```
@Query("FROM Ticket t WHERE ... AND !t.nextActionDate.after(new Date())")
List<Ticket> findOpenedMail();
```

But this fails with `expecting '=', found 't'`. Also I am not sure if `new Date()` will be calculated at the time of query - or already pre-prepared when the Bean is created.

So, what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `date` parameter and use `<`, `>` operators in your query:

```
@Query("FROM Ticket t WHERE ... AND t.nextActionDate < :nextDate ")
List<Ticket> findOpenedMail(@Param("nextDate") Date nextDate);
```

and call `yourRepository.findOpenedMail(new Date());`

Comment: I thought I can do it with a default value namley `today`. But seems like this isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `mysql` you can try annother aproach by changing the date type to Long and save your date in seconds/milliseconds and use the mysql function `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())` (now() is optional) in `nativeQuery`.

```
@Query(value = "select * from ticket t where... and t.next_action_date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()", nativeQuery = true)
List<Ticket> findOpenedMail();
```

`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` will return the current date in seconds.